# Solution Package - List Synchronization

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

How can we use Solution Package (WSP) MOSS 2007 to synchronize lists from one server to another?

Comment: Are you wanting to synchronize the list schema and data?

Comment: If possible, Both. Just the schema and with data.

Comment: Do you mean across site collections? Web applications? Entire SharePoint farms?

Comment: Actually better if I can know how to move items in general. In this case if I am moving from one server to another, guess these should be separate Farms. Also, as I commented below, I want to know a generall method for moving 100s of lists I would create in development to production environment. Don't think if exporting each and every list individually would be a good idea in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this tool: [Content Migration Wizard](http://www.codeplex.com/SPDeploymentWizard)

It allows you to copy lists from farm to farm using the Migration API. You can also script it to run automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Copying data / schema from one server to another is not supported and requires custom code.

Is it really necessary that the items 'exist' on both servers? It sounds error prone to me.  Maybe it's possible to simply **'aggregate'** the items on one server by using a webservice or an RSS feed.

If copying is required then I would create a SharePoint job that runs every x minutes/hours to do the syncronization. Let the custom job communicate with the web services on the other server.

**Note :** Since your job only runs every x minutes it means that your syncronization is not realtime!

Be carefull with large workloads. Make sure you don't stress your server by trying to synchronize 10.000 every minute.

Comment: OK...So how about I created 100 lists in development environment. How should I go about moving those to production environment? Those lists are currently not there in production.

Comment: Save the lists as a template (with or without the data) and upload these templates to the other server. You can do this in your browser. If all the lists share the same layout (columns etc) you only want to save the template once and create all lists from this template

Or you can create a feature and create list definitions. This is a little more advanced and requires XML and SharePoint skills.

Comment: There are also stsadm commands available so you can 'script' the list creation in a batch file and run it all at once.